# How can I set a maximum width for the content of a full-width <section> without a separate <div> element?

Tags: html, css

I'd like the content of some `<section>` which spans the entire page width to be no wider than a specific pixel width (here: 300px). If the page (i.e. the section) is wider than that, the content should be centered horizontally.

To achieve this, I'm currently using a little helper `<div>` which a) defines the maximum width of the content and b) uses a horizontal `auto` margin to center the content horizontally:

```css
section {
  background-color: teal;
}

.content {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="content">
    This text should be no wider than 300px.
  </div>
</section>
```

This works great, but I'm always striving to get rid of such `<div>` elements which are only required for layouting. Ideally, I could use something like `padding: 0 auto;` on the `<section>` element.

Is it possible to achieve the same effect without requiring an extra 'content' `<div>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control the padding like below:

```css
section {
  background-color: teal;
  padding:0 calc((100% - 300px)/2)
}
```

```html
<section>
    This text should be no wider than 300px.
</section>
<section>
    This very long long long text should be no wider than 300px.
</section>
```

Here is another idea using CSS grid:

```css
section {
  background-color: teal;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr minmax(auto,300px) 1fr;
}
/*to fill the 1fr (only the :before is mandatory) */
section:before,
section:after{
  content:"";
}
```

```html
<section>
    This text should be no wider than 300px.
</section>
<section>
    This very long long long text should be no wider than 300px.
</section>
```

Here is another hacky way using flexbox:

```css
section {
  background-color: teal;
  display:flex;
}

section:before,
section:after{
  content:"";
  flex-basis:calc((100% - 300px)/2);
  flex-shrink:0;
}
```

```html
<section>
    This text should be no wider than 300px.
</section>
<section>
    This very long long long text should be no wider than 300px.
</section>
```

Comment: I think your first proposal, using `calc`, looks perfect! Now I just need to sleep over it and overcome my fear of people complaining about the broken layout because their browser does not support using `calc` (this would be the first usage of `calc` in my stylesheet). :-)

Comment: @FrerichRaabe you should be safe, even IE support it ;) https://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
section {
    max-width: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Not sure I get this, the semantic of specifying both `width: 100%` and `max-width:: 300px` isn't clear to me. You're saying that the parent of the `<section>` element needs to have some `width` specified for this to do something?

Comment: The "width: 100%" will set your section to 100% width, until max-width limits it to 300px. As long as a width is set, "margin: 0 auto" will keep the section centered once the viewport is larger than 300px. Ignore my comment about the parent; edited

Comment: Ah, yes. However, this sets the margin whereas I'd like to set the padding. I'd like the background color to still span the entire width of the page as in my little code example and just limit the content of the section to a certain width.

Comment: @Frerich ahhh I see, my apologies as I misunderstood that part of the question. Temani's answer is your ticket then.